# converting/mapping linux reference path without altering the file?

Tags: python, maya

Currently on a project that my client needs the reference file path to
remain in linux format. For example

```
A.ma , referencing objects from --> //linux/project/scene/B.ma
B.ma , referencing objects from --> //linux/project/scene/C.ma
```

Most of our Maya license here however are on Windows. I can run a
Python script that convert all the paths  windows paths and save the
file. For example

```
Z:\project\scene\B.ma
```

However I'm trying to figure out a way to do this ***without*** converting
or altering the original file.... I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do.

- Run the script to open the file.
- The script checks for the linux formatted reference path, and all
  child path down the hierarchy.
- Maps all paths to their appropriate windows formatted paths.
- Giving the animators the ability to "save" files normally without running a separate save script.

Is this possible to achieve this with Python script? Or will I need a
fully-compiled plug in to get this to work?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

---

edit: Thank you for your input.

A little more clarification. The projects were set up for us by a remote company and part of the requirement is that we have to keep the path as is. They come as absolute path and we have no choice in that matter.

We match the mount  `//linux/` on our Fedora workstations. That same drive is mapped to `Z:\` on our windows workstations. We only have 2 Maya license for Linux tho which is why I'm trying to do this.

Comment: Couldn't you use relative paths instead of absolute paths?

Comment: What's wrong with a remote mount of the Linux file system on Windows machines?

Comment: Thanks Andrea, Lott for your reply. It's a requirement that we have to keep the path "as is" so we have no choice in that matter. While a scripts can convert all these easily, it means we will either have to overwrite the existing files or need to duplicate all the directories tho which I want to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. First step is to create a `dict` that keeps track of linux/windows references (don't forget to import the `re` module for regexp):

```
>>> def windows_path(path):
    return path.replace('//linux', 'Z:').replace('/', '\\')

>>> reg = re.compile('(\w+\.ma) , referencing objects from --> (.*)')
>>> d = {}
>>> for line in open('D:\\temp\\Toto.txt'):
    match = reg.match(line)
    if match:
        file_name = match.groups()[0]
        linux_path = match.groups()[1]
        d[file_name] = (linux_path, windows_path(linux_path))


>>> d
{'B.ma': ('//linux/project/scene/C.ma', 'Z:\\project\\scene\\C.ma'),
 'A.ma': ('//linux/project/scene/B.ma', 'Z:\\project\\scene\\B.ma')}
```

Then you just need to loop on this `dict` to ask for file save:

```
>>> for file_name in d.keys():
    s = raw_input('do you want to save file %s ? ' % file_name)
    if s.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
        # TODO: save your file thanks to d[file][0] for linux path, 
        # d[file][1] for windows path
        print '-> file %s was saved' % file_name
    else:
        print '-> file %s was not saved' % file_name


do you want to save file B.ma ? n
-> file B.ma was not saved
do you want to save file A.ma ? yes
-> file A.ma was saved
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel for your reply. I thought about running a script to do the conversion too but that would mean I need to do it in another copy of the directory (because the original one needs to be kept the way it is) I would love to have Maya able to use path as I specify instead without converting the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Many Windows applications will interpret paths with two leading "/"s as UNC paths. I don't know if Maya is one of those, but try it out. If Maya can understand paths like "//servername/share/foo", then all you need to do is set up a SMB server named "linux", and the paths will work as they are. I would guess that this is actually what your client does, since the path "//linux" would not make sense in a Linux-only environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to do this.  Maya will expand environment vars present in a file path, you could use Maya.env to set them up properly for each platform.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the **dirmap** *mel command*. It is completely non-intrusive to your files as you just define a mapping from your linux paths to windows and/or vice versa. Maya will internally apply the mapping to resolve the paths, without changing them when saving the file.

To setup dirmap, you need to run a MEL script which issues the respective commands on maya startup. UserSetup.mel could be one place to put it.

For more details, see the official documentation - this particular link points to maya 2012, the command is available in Maya 7.0 and earlier as well though:
http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/Commands/dirmap.html